# Optocoupler circuit to shift from 3.3V to 15V

Tags: transistors, signal, opto-isolator, signal-processing, phototransistor

I am trying to use the circuit below to shift a squared wave form (2kHz) with a peak of 3.3VDC to one with a peak at 15VDC. I am trying to do that with the circuit below, I am using the optocoupler HCPL 2531.

When I measure the voltage between **V_out** and **V_out_gnd** I get what I expect. However, when I connect a load of 10kohms between **V_out** and **V_out_gnd** the peak voltage on the output changes to 9.5V. I tried to solve the issue connecting a resistor (33kohms) in series with my load (10kohm), but then Vout drops to 3V.

Does anybody know how to fix this? Thanks!

[image: This is the circuit I am testing. I am using the optocoupler HCPL 2531]

Comment: Do you need to have galvanic isolation here? Could you just do this with a transistor?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior globally seems normal do me :

- if the photo-transistor is "closed", pin 7 is connected to ground : Vout=0V
- if the photo-transistor is "open", then pin 7 is connected to "nothing", excepted to what you connect it externally. So if you have only the pull up resistor, then you pull the output up at 15V. If you add your 10k resistor between Vout and ground, then it acts as a pull down resistor. So basically, you get a voltage divider between your R6=5.6k and the 10k resistor (let's call it R7).
  So the expected value of Vout is 15V*R7/(R6+R7)=15*10/(10+5.6)=9.5V.
  NB : I don't find your 6.5V, which surprises me a bit (can you double check the values of R6 and R7 you used?)

Anyway, to solve the problem, I have 2 suggestions :

1. use a load resistor much bigger than R6, so that the voltage divider gives you a voltage close to 15V
2. use an OpAmp (operational amplifier) between Vout and whatever you want to connect to it (for example the 10k resistor, or anything else drawing some current (within the limitation of the OpAm you choose). NB : if you don't have any voltage above 15V available, then use a rail-to-tail OpAmp to have the output near 15V (with standard OpAmps you need a supply voltage 1 to 2 volts above the maximal output voltage you need)

Comment: Correction: when I connect the 10Kohm resistor on Vout the voltage drops to 9.5V. I tried connecting a 33kohm resistor in series with my load (10Kohm resistor) on Vout, and Vout dropped to 3V peak.

Answer (score 0):

> When I measure the voltage between V_out and V_out_gnd I get what I expect. However, when I connect a 10kohms resistor between V_out and V_out_gnd the peak voltage on the output changes to 6.5V.

Using R5=220, R6=5.6k and Load to gnd = 10k then because the collector is a current sink and thus high impedance, the output ideally if CTR is sufficient, sees a voltage divider 10k/(10k+5.6k)*15V= 9.6V , yet you only got 6.5 implies your CTR is insufficient which is due the current gain like Beta or hFE of any transistor scaled down due to the optical losses internally.

A rough check on input current If= (3.3-1.5)/220= 8.2 mA while the output current can be computed using Thevenin Equivalents for the load.  from above Veq=9.6V and Req= 5.6k//10k=3.6kohm thus Ic= 9.6V/3.6kohm= 2.67 mA so your CTR was 2.67m/8.2m= 32.5% . Yet from the datasheet p3 CTR is only 19% min and 27% typ, so your CTR was insufficient.

This means you must decide on what Vout is acceptable with a 10 k load  for output high , Voh (min) 15- 10%? then choose R6 and R5 for CTR = 19% min.

Although this Opto is now obsolete, you basically use the worst-case CTR to choose the current ratios with the desired threshold.

CTR 19%min 27typ 50%max @ If=16 mA, Vol=0.5V

19% CTR * 16 mA = Ic = 3 mA

Vf = 1.45 V typ , 1.7 max at If = 16 mA

If you choose Vol=0.5 and you don't have to, you can use your interface Vil max. then apply KVL to compute R with worst-case supply voltages.

For Rin , presume (3.3V-1.7)/16 mA = **Rin =100 ohms**  (=R5+Rol of CMOS driver ~ 33 to 66 ohms typ.)
For Rout, presume (15V-0.5)/3 mA = **Rc  = 4.83 Kohm** choose nearest    (R6)

**This results in a minimum current ratio of 16/3=5.33 and a voltage ratio of 15/3.3=4.5 and a resistor ratio of 48:1**

More modern or better Opto IC's will have a reduction of this ratio with higher detector efficacy or a larger u-chip.

When you identify the driver and the Vol/Iol=Rol you will realize the source impedance can be almost 50% of the 100 ohm calculation. This means Rin must be reduced to get the correct 16 mA to guarantee performance from batch to batch.

### Caveat

I may consider the fact this 10 MHz part is running slow (2kHz) and so current driving capacitance loading effects (T=RC) may be neglected for 2kHz and thus be able to increase the collector resistance (thereby reducing Ic) by up to a factor of 100 or so albeit I will conservatively reduce it by only 1/10 . Thus reduce the **input current down from 16 mA to 3mA and output current from 3mA to 0.3mA** . Observing the datasheet , figure 1  where If=3mA and 16mA have the same normalized gain= CTR=1 which is just the typical curve for the conditions given. Ta=25'C Vo = 0.4V

Thus the result can be relaxed to typical voltages Vf=1.45typ,  (3.3V-1.45)/ 3mA = **Rin = 617 ohms**
Choose 10% of the previous Ic= 3mA rather than 100x smaller,

(15V- 0.5V)/0.3mA = **Rc= 48kohm**

But if you really have to load the output with 10k, this won't work.

### Rev 2 design specs (goes back to the original values.)

IFF (if and only if) you cannot change the load of 10k to something like >=100k then  you must go back to the original recommended values and verify my assumptions and decide if this is for 1 unit or many ! then you would use worst-case rather than something below typ.

Choose CMOS Vol/Iol and assume Rout= 50 ohms then use **R5 = 50 ohms to achieve 16 mA for If.**

The R6 value affects the Vo max with a 10 k load, so I cannot make this choice for you... There are compromises with this IC and your load that will not guarantee full 15V output unless you overdrive the LED recommended If =16mA and suffer more CTR loss of performance from fig 1. then you have to consider the power dissipation in the CMOS driver and it's rated do not exceed value. You do not need to consider the CMOS logic levels for an LED drive current.

### Conclusion

- This obsolete IC can be improved and the load reconsidered to improve output swing.